# jQuery hiding all trs or tds not just one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to compare a date from an input field to the ones displayed in my table. However, when matched, it hides all tds and erases the column, if I use the .parent() it hides all trs when matches so I have an empty table.

jQuery :

```
$('[name="dateFrom"]').on("change", function () {
    var dateFrom = new Date($(this).val());
    var conditionDateFrom = $('td[name="tdDateFrom');
    conditionDateFrom.hide();
    conditionDateFrom.filter(function () {
        return dateFrom < new Date(conditionDateFrom.html());
    }).show();

});
```

input:

```
<input name="dateFrom" type="date" value="2016-01-01" />
```

the td I am trying to match

```
<td name="tdDateFrom">{{ a.StartDate | date:'longDate'}}</td>
```

I just want to hide the one tr where it matches the td.

Thanks

---

Cannot get a jsfiddle to work but here is a screen of the console + table

The table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7VzP.jpg

The console when logging  https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcKnb.jpg

```
        var test = new Date(conditionDateFrom.html());
        console.log(test);
```

Only seems to be checking the condition of the first tr?

---

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jp3jf25a/ similar to my code, however for me the table is being affected, cannot get it to work on the fiddle

Comment: typo in `var conditionDateFrom = $('td[name="tdDateFrom"]');` ?

Comment: I don't think so, it's grabbing the td's name

Comment: Use conditionDateFrom.detach(); instead of conditionDateFrom.hide();

Comment: You talk about hiding `tr` but you only match `td` what are you trying to hide? Can you show the full table?

Comment: @PierreC. editting post right now

Comment: Can you create fiddle of it

Comment: Trying to but it's not working :s

Comment: It would be better to have the table with actual values. So we can test out.

Comment: i could not get the jsfiddle to work but I posted some screenshots, will try to get jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q55n85xe/1/)

Various issues:

- By using `conditionDateFrom.html()` you are hiding all of the tds, instead you should use `$(this).text()`.
- Filter on the trs not tds, you want to hide the rows that don't match instead of hiding individual tds
- Skip the first tr because that is the table headers
- Use `<=` not `<` because an equal date should show
- Handle when the input is blank (should show all again)

Updated code:

```
$('[name="dateFrom"]').on("change", function () {
    var conditionDateFrom = $('.table tr');

    if($(this).val() == ''){
        conditionDateFrom.show();
        return;
    }

    var dateFrom = new Date($(this).val());

    conditionDateFrom.hide();
    conditionDateFrom.filter(function (index) {
        return index == 0 || dateFrom <= new Date($(this).children('td[name="tdDateFrom"]').text());
    }).show();
});
```

Comment: I notice in your jsfiddle it is not hiding the headers, but in my code it is, even though they are tr>th not tr>td, any ideas?

Comment: To skip the headers, I've captured the `index` argument and checking `index == 0` in the filter.

Comment: It didn't seem to work for me, but I just changed the condition variable to target tr's with name filter, thanks again a ton for the help.

Answer (score 0):

let's breakdown your problem, you want to hide only the first match i guess But instead you are fetching all the matches.`$('td[name="tdDateFrom')` will fetch you all matches instead of that you can get only first match by `$('td[name="tdDateFrom').first()`.

```
`$('td[name="tdDateFrom').first().parent('tr')` will return you only the one matched tr element.
```

here is updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jp3jf25a/1/

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work to select the appropriate tr.

```
var inputValue = $(input).attr('value') //'2016-01-01'
var conditionDateFrom = $("td:contains(inputValue)").parent()
```

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

edited after realizing you want the parent tr (I think?)